# About "Times New Roman" with Greek characters, Italic characters and Bold characters

Tags: fonts, bold, greek, italic, times

I'm japanese student, so i am not good at using English. Sorry.

I want to use Bold Greek characters, Bold Italic Greek characters and Italic Greek characters with using "Times New Roman".
But, now all of these is too duty not to want to use these.
By the way, i tried these package, "platex", "txfonts".
I want to know the method of displaying beauty characters. Please give me some advices.

There is a priamble code...

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: do you want greek text or greek letters in math mode? (these typically need different font sets)

Comment: Thanks for your responding. i want to use greek text or letters in math mode.

Comment: ``1.`` Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.
``2.`` A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).